# SQL table display without linebreaks in HTML webpage

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to display a paragraph of text (stored in a SQL table) in html.
The problem I have is, all the linebreaks gets removed when it is displayed on the webpage.

The text would be like:  
Day 1,  
This is the first day.  
The day is done at last.  
  
And it would display like:  
Day 1,  This is the first day.  The day is done at last.

- I have originally used 'TEXT', but changed to 'VARCHAR'.
- The    text has been manually inserted into my phpAdmin in the cpanel

The code is

```
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT tablea.id, tableb.id, tablea.name, tablea.surn, tableb.messg, tableb.tdate, tableb.person, FROM tablea INNER JOIN msgs ON tablea.id=tableb.id WHERE id=$id ORDER BY tdate ASC")

or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {

                ?>

            <div>

                <div>

                    <p>
                        <?php echo strtoupper($row["person"]); ?>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <?php echo $row["messg"]; ?>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <?php echo $row["tdate"]; ?>
                    </p>

                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the line breaks to HTML line breaks (< br />) using the `nl2br()` function.

Comment: Thanks! Works great. So the conclusion is:  

        <?php echo nl2br($row["messg"]); ?>     
Any idea why this was caused? Its the first time I came across something like this